# Handle heavy resource/DOM on React Portal

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

I have created a react portal inside my application to handle the use of Modal. The portal target is outside of my React root div as sibling of my root element.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="root">{{app.html}}</div>
      <div id="modal-root">
         <div class="modal" tabIndex="-1" id="modal-inner-root" role="dialog">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

So my Portal contents renders outside of the react application and its working fine. Here is my react portal code

```
const PortalRawModal = (props) => {
    const [ display, setDisplay ] = useState(document.getElementById("modal-inner-root").style.display)
    const div = useRef(document.createElement('div'))

    useEffect(()=> {
        const modalInnerRoot = document.getElementById("modal-inner-root")
        if(validate(props.showModalId)) {
            if( props.showModalId == props.modalId && _.size(props.children) > 0 ) {
                setDisplay("block");
                if(_.size(modalInnerRoot.childNodes) > 0) {
                    modalInnerRoot.replaceChild(div.current,modalInnerRoot.childNodes[0]);
                } else {
                    modalInnerRoot.appendChild(div.current);
                }
                div.current.className = props.modalInner;
                document.getElementById("modal-root").className = props.modalClassName;
                document.body.className = "modal-open";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("modal-root").className = props.modalClassName;
                if(div.current.parentNode == modalInnerRoot) {
                    modalInnerRoot.removeChild(div.current);
                    div.current.className = "";
                }
            }
        } else {
            setDisplay("none");
            document.getElementById("modal-root").className = "";
            if(div.current.parentNode == modalInnerRoot) {
                modalInnerRoot.removeChild(div.current).className = "";
            }
            document.body.className = "";
        }
    },[ props.showModalId ])

    useEffect(()=> {
        document.body.className = display == "none" ? "" : "modal-open";
        document.getElementById("modal-inner-root").style.display = display;

        return () => {
            if(!validate(props.showModalId)) {
                document.body.className = "";
                document.getElementById("modal-inner-root").style.display = "none"
            }
        };
    },[ display])

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(_.size(props.children) <= 0){
            modalInnerRoot.removeChild(div.current)
            document.body.className = "";
            document.getElementById("modal-inner-root").style.display = "none";
        }

        return () => {
            if(_.size(props.children) <= 0){
                modalInnerRoot.removeChild(div.current)
                document.body.className = "";
                document.getElementById("modal-inner-root").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    },[props.children, props.showModalId])

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(props.children ,div.current);
}
```

Whenever the children are passed and modal is mounted, The heavy DOM is painted with little delay. But the same markup takes time, or even crashes the browser tab. Where am I going wrong in handling the heavy DOM operations? Or is there any `async` way to handle the heavy DOM operations that wont effect the overall performance?

Comment: why do you need to manipulate DOM directly instead of using normal React components? (you can use React components inside a Portal just fine)

Comment: I followed the modal example in the official docs of React Portal (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) which also manipulates the DOM directly using `document`. Adding is not the issue but removing causes performance issue here

Comment: aah, my question was about why do YOU need to do it please? the documentation contains an example solution to an example problem, but I expect that you have a different problem (your code is much more complex than the example, why do you think you need a portal and why do you need custom DOM inside that portal?)...

Comment: @AhsanAhmed : In those examples only `hide`, `unhide` of the modal container element is done through DOM. It does not do any logical updates.

Comment: I would recommend to use [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) library for simple Modal feature, unless you can explain what complex DOM manipulation are necessary for your use case

Comment: @Aprillion The main reason for using Portal is to eject the modal markup outside of the DOM hierarchy for the ease of many use cases. The challenge was, how the Children that are in the hierarchy are passed to that modal. React Portal seemed the best solution.

Comment: @Easwar at first I used `react-modal` which populates my DOM outside of the hierarchy (which was my original intention for modal) but it also causes the problem when unmounting the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of reasons can attribute for this :

- The last effect will always run for every re-render as `props.children` is an object and hence even if same children was passed again, it'll be a new object.
- Direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern, as React maintains several DOM references in memory for fast diffing, hence direct mutation may result in some perf hit.Try writing the same in a declarative fashion.
- Extract out the portal content into another sub-component and avoid DOM manipulations wherever possible.

One place would be :

```
if (_.size(props.children) <= 0) {
  modalInnerRoot.removeChild(div.current);
}
```

can be replaced within the render function like :

```
{React.Children.count(props.children) ? <div /> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to **use the modal root as the `createPortal` host `div`** (the second argument). React will just render there instead of in the regular element.

Then if you need to "manipulate" the HTML, just use plain React. It does not work any differently inside of portaled elements. All `createPortal` does is tell React to take this part of the tree and attach it under specified element.

Just include a permanent empty div with no style (no need to use any display rules), and it will just receive all HTML you want to render. Then you make the content inside the modal root `fixed`, but not the modal root itself.

#### Don't do this:

```
const div = useRef(document.createElement('div'))
// all kinds of manipulation of this div
return ReactDOM.createPortal(props.children ,div.current);
```

#### Do this instead:

```
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

function ModalWrapper({children}) {
    return <div class="modal" id="modal-inner-root" role="dialog">
        { children }
     </div>
}

function PortalModal({children}) {
    return React.createPortal(
        <ModalWrapper>{ children }</ModalWrapper>,
        modalRoot 
}

function App() {
    const [hasConfirmed, setHasConfirmed] = useState(false);

    return <div>
        // ...
        { !hasConfirmed && <PortalModal>
             <h1> Please confirm </h1>
             <button onClick={() => setHasConfirmed(true)}>
                 Yes
             </button>
        </PortalModal> }
    </div>
}
```

You can perfectly manage the state of the component in the modal, and whether it should show the modal at all. You won't need to do any manual DOM manipulation anymore.

Once you stop rendering the portal, React removes it for you.

---

### Why does the question's code have performance issues?

It does many DOM operations which, among other things, will result in style recalculations. You shouldn't have to do manual DOM operations at all, it's exactly what React is built to handle for you. And it's reasonably efficient at it.

Since you're doing it in `useEffect`, React has already triggered style recalculations and the result of that was painted to the screen. This is now immediately invalidated, and the browser needs to recalculate some amount of elements.

Which amount of elements?... All of them, because a **style recalculation on the `body`** is triggered by changing its classname.

```
document.body.className = "modal-open";
```

If you have a heavy DOM, a full style recalculation can quickly take long and cause noticeable stutter. You can avoid this by not touching the body and just adding an overlay `div` you can show and hide.

Can it cause a tab to crash though? Maybe in extreme cases, but probably not.

It's more likely that you're calling this component in a way that creates an infinite loop. Or you may be ending up doing a ridiculous amount of DOM operations. It's impossible to tell without the full code used when the performance issues were noted.